# How to prevent firing the p:filepload

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, primefaces

I have something like this:

```
<h:form id="form">

    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{jSFmanageBean.fileUpload}" 
                  update="gallery"
                  mode="advanced"
                  auto="true" 
                  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"   />

    <p:dataGrid var="car" 
                value="#{jSFmanageBean.cars}" 
                id="gallery" >
        <p:panel header="#{car.id}" 
                 style="text-align:center" 
                 id="testSomething">
            <p:graphicImage alt="ERROR2" 
                            value="#{jSFmanageBean.image2}"  
                            width="250">
                <f:param name="id" value="#{car.id}" />
            </p:graphicImage>
        </p:panel>
    </p:dataGrid>

    <p:commandLink update=":form:carDetail" 
                   oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()" 
                   title="View Detail">
        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search" 
                      style="margin:0 auto;" />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" 
                                     target="#{jSFmanageBean.selectedCar}" />
    </p:commandLink>

    <p:dialog header="Car Info" 
              widgetVar="carDialog" 
              modal="true" 
              showEffect="fade" 
              hideEffect="fade" 
              resizable="false">
        <p:outputPanel id="carDetail" 
                       style="text-align:center;">
            <p:panelGrid  columns="2" 
                          rendered="#{not empty jSFmanageBean.selectedCar}" 
                          columnClasses="label,value">

                <h:outputText value="Id:" />
                <h:outputText value="#{jSFmanageBean.selectedCar.id}" />

            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

The problem is when i try to use "p:commandLink" the "p:fileUpload" component is fired (or something like that) and i have error.

```
Warning:   javax.servlet.ServletException: The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.servlet.ServletException: The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data
at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.NativeFileUploadDecoder.decode(NativeFileUploadDecoder.java:44)
at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer.decode(FileUploadRenderer.java:44)
.
.
.
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: The request content-type is not a multipart/form-data
.
.
```

How to prevent firing the FileUpload when i using other ajax things in the same form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are processing the whole form when you are clicking in the `p:commandLink` because is submit type by default. Without knowing too much of your purposes, one easy way to prevent that would be adding `process="@this"` to your `p:commandLink` to avoid processing the rest of the form (if you want to process more things you can add them):

```
<p:commandLink update=":form:carDetail" process="@this"
               oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()" 
               title="View Detail">
```